# C++ stack allocation for vector

Tags: c++

What would happen on stack for the following code?

Specifically I think temp should be stored on stack right?

Then when temp is reassigned to a new vacant vector, how about the previous temp which contains 2 and 3?

It is deleted not on stack anymore?

Who delete that?

```
int main() {
vector<int> temp;
temp.push_back(2);
temp.push_back(3);
temp = vector<int>();
}
```

Comment: "Then when temp is reassigned to a new vacant vector" -- No. The value of the temporary empty vector is assigned to `temp`. The object `temp` still exists, it's lifetime exists until the end of scope. Only its internal state is modified by the assignment operator.

Comment: Why do you need to know the physical memory location? Code to specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step.

```
int main() {
vector<int> temp;
```

The above line creates a local variable of type `vector<int>`. The members of the `vector` class live on the stack.

The `vector` creates may allocate a default amount of `int` on the heap.  *(Note: The `vector` class may wait for the first `push_back` in order to allocate on the heap.)*

```
temp.push_back(2);
```

The vector allocates a default amount of `int` on the heap if necessary.
The parameter is copied into the first slot (on the heap).
State variables within the vector are updated.
The space allocation on the stack is not changed.

```
temp.push_back(3);
```

The vector places the value 3 into the 2nd slot of the memory allocated on the heap.
State variables within the vector are updated.
The space allocation on the stack is not changed.

```
temp = vector<int>();
```

The `temp` is assigned to a new vector.
The old vector values on the heap are deallocated.
State variables within the vector are updated.
The space allocation on the stack is not changed.

```
}
```

The `temp` vector is removed from the stack (its destructor is called).
The stack should be the same size as before `main` executed.

The vector's destructor deletes the memory it allocated from the heap.

**Edit 1:**
*Note: the storage of the vector's elements is implementation dependent.  A vector could store it's data on the stack (such has having a default area for elements in the class).  A common implementation is to use the heap for the elements.*

Comment: _"The vector creates may allocate a default amount of int on the heap."_ What on earth is this supposed to mean? And would you please stop propagating this stack/heap nonsense? C++ is an _abstraction_ from such implementation details, very much by design.

Comment: Sorry, using beginner's language -- heap and stack.  A vector creates a default area in dynamic memory to store the `int`s.  Meaning there is an initial, default capacity of the vector.

Comment: I wish we would stop using "wrong language" and calling it "beginner's language", especially when the beginners are the worst affected by this habit. As for capacity, that's 100% unspecified. It could/might/will/would/may be no initial capacity whatsoever.